# Auth0 login locally

Tags: auth0

I have an application and an api, in terms of auth0, an static frontend and a expressjs backend, in production both are working. I setup Auth0 and users are able to login with Google accounts.

In production is working, but the problem I am facing is when I am working on my locally, when I run the application on my computer and I try to login I get the following error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Request failed with status code 401
```

In the application setup I have

```
Allowed Callback URLs

https://www.myexample.com, http://localhost:3000, https://myexample.us.auth0.com/api/v2/

Allowed Logout URLs

https://www.myexample.com, http://localhost:3000

Allowed Web Origins

https://www.myexample.com, http://localhost:3000
```

and in the frontend

```
<Auth0Provider
  domain="myexample.us.auth0.com"
  clientId="XXXXXXXXXXX"
  redirectUri={(process.browser) ? window && window.location.origin : 'http://localhost:3000'}
  audience="https://myexample.us.auth0.com/api/v2/"
  scope="read:current_user update:current_user_metadata"
>
```

If further information is needed, just let me know

I am not sure if I am missing some config or there is something I should change?